# Print LABEL text in multiple lines in Cesium JS API

Tags: labeling, printing, cesium

I have a problem printing text in multiple lines using Label in Cesium JavaScript API. text is member of Label class which takes String as input but doesn't really support multiple line labels using `'\n'` character (typically as in Java `string1 + '\n' + string2`). Is there any way of printing labels in multiple lines?

Comment: using '\r\n' instead of just '\n' worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE, 2017-Jan-02:** Cesium 1.29 was released today with official support for multi-line labels, added in [#4306](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/4306).  The newline `'\n'` character is now accepted as a line break.

---

Original answer:

This feature is desired but not yet implemented.  There is some code in [issue #2575](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/2575) that implements this, but is not yet ready to merge into master.  I'll ping the issue and see if there can be any more progress on this.

In the meantime, you can emulate the feature by placing multiple labels with different Y pixel offsets.

Comment: I guess this topic also opens up a discussion on rendering html content / something similar to `placemark.setDescription` on billboard in Cesium. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: That should be a separate question, or a discussion on the [Cesium mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cesium-dev).  But generally, if you're using Cesium Entities, you can assign an entity a description that includes HTML, and the HTML will be placed in a sandboxed iframe when the entity is selected.

Comment: For example, try clicking on any object in the [CZML Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/CZML.html).

Comment: Yes. You are right. I got the same answer on the post in Cesium forums